# How can I achieve unit safety in Stylus?

Tags: css, stylus, type-safety

I'm trying to use a CSS preprocessor in my project, and so I chose Stylus. Today I've discovered that Stylus compiles this:

```
body {
  width: 100% + 50px;
}
```

To this:

```
body {
  width: 150%;
}
```

This can be vary surprising when both values are variables. For example if I have some expression in my rules like this:

```
my-element {
  width: $some-value + $some-other-value + $some-more-value;
}
```

And if I change the units of one of these variables, for example, from pixels to percent, then the expression will silently break. So if I want to change units I have to review all usages of this variable all over the project and check if it's OK or not.

Is there any way to achieve some kind of unit safety in stylus? A perfect solution will be if Stylus could generate `calc(100% + 50px)` for this kind of situation and give me a warning in the console. But even just a warning or error somewhere would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use native CSS calc, and not the stylus version, you can use [sprintf](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/operators.html#sprintf) to achieve it. It will resolve different units like you expect, unlike how stylus handles the math by converting units. Ex:

```
width: 'calc(%s + %s + %s)' % ($some-value $some-other-value $some-more-value)
```